# iterating json array in scala html file using for loop

Tags: html, scala, backbone.js

I have to iterate JsonArray whose objects have a property named as "path". i have to fetch that path and display image for each path.

Comment: How did you define `myJsonArr`?

Comment: its coming from backbone.js file where its getting populated by server side code , its format is like [{"path":" xxx   ","name":" xxx"},{........}]

Answer (score 1):

you should return myJsonArr

> Controller:
>
> ```
> ex: return ok(views.html.render(myJsonArr));
> ```

.

> Scala Html
>
> ```
> @(myJsonArr:Map[String,String])
>
> @for(s <- myJsonArr){
>     <img src="@s.get("path")" width="50" height="50"/>
>  }
> ```

This is how I do.

Answer (score 0):

I just assume that this is from a template file from the Play framework. If so, then the syntax should look like this:

```
@for(item <- myJsonArr) {
   <img src="@item.path" width="50" height="50"/>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, in play templates you could operate only with data on the server side.

This means that any values should be known to request handler, and accessible via other server scala\java code, while your `GET` request is processed.

Json data, that is known to your client, i.e. browser, even if it's fetched from another request to same server, could be processed only in javascript.

If you really like to generate HTML via template from some client-side data, you should pass it to server with request first [see about request parameters](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.9/ScalaRouting)

Also if you are greatly encouaged with handling data on client side via scala you may be interested in the [scala js project](http://www.scala-js.org/)